SAGE 300 -- Cannot Access DB (error = 49153)
I have created a user using the oracle em, I then created a new database using the sage 300 database set up tool.  I provided a data source ( which is used for another company and is working fine), the Login ID, password, and tablespace then clicked okay.  That worked fine.
I then performed a database dump and database load using the sage 300 utilities.  All worked fine then when I logged into the new created database, to create user that worked fine. When I try to log into the new company I get the 49513 error.
Any ideas?
I have tried adding records to the CSAUTH table,  I have tried ensuring the user I created for the database setup has DBA permissions, and can connect.

https://communityhub.sage.com/us/sage300/f/general-discussion/174715/database-setup-unable-to-connect-to-database-error-49153
